# Navigating to website yields Code: NoSuchBucket when using cloudflare

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloudflare

So I am currently using Cloudflare for my DNS under the domain `www.movez.co` but for some reason when someone types in `http://movez.co` directly into their web browser it spits back this:

```
404 Not Found

Code: NoSuchBucket
Message: The specified bucket does not exist

BucketName: movez.co

RequestId: 64038C65xxx

HostId: xxx
```

Of course our bucked is named `www.movez.co` and our root record is pointed to the correct bucket (`www.movez.co.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`) and our www CNAME record is pointed to the root as an alias. The bucket is publicly accessible but for some reason in specific iPhone users are getting put to the 404 page.

Can anyone help me figure out why this is occurring? 
I've tried purging cache and there's no redirect redirect records with our registrar (GoDaddy)..

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the CNAME operates on the DNS level, not on the HTTP level. The CNAME will cause the request to be forwarded to the IP address for `www.movez.co.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com`, but the HTTP request will still say it's looking for `moves.co`. The HTTP request doesn't contain `www.movez.co.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com` nor `www.moves.co` anywhere in the request, so Amazon has no way to know that the request should be served from the bucket for `www.movez.co`.

I suggest setting up a Page Rule in Cloudflare which redirects the client's browser from `movez.co` to `www.movez.co`. If you don't want to use a browser redirect, then either you'll need to configure Amazon to understand `movez.co` (maybe by creating a whole separate bucket), or perhaps you could use a Cloudflare Worker to rewrite the HTTP requests (but you'll need to pay extra to Cloudflare for that).